# Indent on all Auto Layout constraints in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout

I have a custom `UITableViewCell` which I have laid out in Interface Builder and added the necessary constraints.

The content view of my cell always fills the entirety of the cell, but I'm noticing that all subviews of the content view are inset by 8 points. The constraints all have a constant of 0. I have set the layoutMargins of the view to be UIEdgeInsetsZero. Is there some default behaviour in iOS 8 that I'm forgetting?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: when you bind constraint in cell. it will add constraint relative to margin. you can remove that. follow steps > tap on that constraint> right side navigator> tap on (first item or second item) > you can see that "relative to margin" option is on. just uncheck that option and you'll get proper position.

Comment: Thanks, this did the trick. If you post as the answer I can accept it. Is there any way to make this the default behaviour for the entire view?

Comment: i dont think so maybe because this is only in ios8. if your target is 7&8 then you'll get warning for "Layout attribute relative to the layout margin on iOS versions prior to 8.0". and if your target is only 8 then you wont get warning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Follow the steps

tap on that constraint > right side navigator > tap on (first item or second item) > you can see that "relative to margin" option is on. just uncheck that option and you'll get proper position.

Comment: I just noticed when adding a constraint in IB you can uncheck the box "Constrain to margins"

Comment: @Ricky yes when adding constraint using bottom "pin" option. but if you add constraint using TopMenu > Editor option > pin . then you won't get that option :)

Comment: Do you know if there's a way to override the value of 8?

Comment: Turns out you need to set the `layoutMargins` property of the cell's content view.

Comment: @Ricky i didnt find it. can you tell me steps?like i said you lol.

Comment: For example when dequeueing the cell, you can set the layoutMargins property. 
`cell.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsMake(8, self.tableView.layoutMargins.left, 8, self.tableView.layoutMargins.right);
cell.contentView.layoutMargins = cell.layoutMargins;`

Comment: This of course is applied at runtime, I'm not sure if you can change Interface Builder's default.