# ContentView in UITableView cell has offset

Tags: ios, uitableview

Doing it in a xib:
For some reason the `contentView` has an offset of 8px, although it has no constraints to it's parnet view (and I can't set one myself)

How can I set it to 0?

Comment: I think you have to set the separator inset to custom in the tableview properties, and then set it to 0 ?

Comment: the xib file doesn't know the tableview... anyhow I have other xib files and other tabelviews with Default and it works perfectly...

Comment: @Boaz Check out this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26351940/indent-on-all-auto-layout-constraints-in-uitableviewcell) . Maybe this will help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Constrain to margins. Set this property no. Its a new property. On constraint window.