# why there is a inset in tableviewcell's contentView when using xib and auto layout?

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout

I want to make a constraint between the imageView's leading to the cell'contentView's leading ,but in xib ,i found that ,there already be some strange inset when i add constraints. it seems like when  i make the constraints to 8 , the distance will be 16(or so) actually , and in the picture , we can see that the T bar can't reach the left edge of the contentView, what mechanism make this inset happens? and can i turn this inset off?
[image]

Comment: check out my answer and you can remove margin. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26351940/indent-on-all-auto-layout-constraints-in-uitableviewcell/26352298#26352298)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your constraint is probably aligned to Container Margin instead of Container. Change it to Container and it will align without the inset margin.

Answer (score 3):

What you can do is:

1) Click the UIImageView.

2) Select the Pin tool in the bottom right corner (its the second from the left).

3) Uncheck "constrain to margin"

4) Set your leading edge to 8 points then click add constraint

Answer (score 0):

Choose the conentView, and go to its size inspector. There, under Layout Margins, change the value from Default to Explicit. Then you can set the margins to 0.